# How can I bring the tooltip to the top of chart

Tags: css, charts, tooltip

I now have a google chart like this bellow picture

[image]

Now I want to move the tooltip to the top of chart (dont care the position of my mouse).

How can I do it.

Here is my code :

```
var chartData = new google.visualization.DataTable();
chartData.addColumn('string', 'Time');
chartData.addColumn('number', 'Average Score');
chartData.addColumn({ 'type': 'string', 'role': 'tooltip', 'p': { 'html': true } });

chartData.addRows(data);

var options = {
    chartArea: { left: 0, top: 100, width: "100%", height: "100%" },
    title: '',
    opacity: 100,
    backgroundColor : {fill: '#000'},
    hAxis: {
        textPosition: 'none', 
        titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'},  
        titleTextStyle: {color: '#2902A3'},
    },
    vAxis: {
        textPosition: 'none',
        opacity: 100,
        minValue: 0,
        gridlines: { color: '#0D2B56', count: 10 },
        baselineColor: 'white',
    },
    series:{
        0:{
            color: '#3C93FF',
            areaOpacity: '0.68'
        }
    },
    crosshair: {
        orientation: 'vertical',
        trigger: 'focus',
        color: '#fff'
    },
    legend: 'none',
    tooltip: {isHtml: true},
};


google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
chart.draw(chartData, options);
```

I also use this function to create tooltip's content

```
var createToolTip = function (name, value) {
    return '<div class="googletooltip" ><span>' + name + ':</span><span style="padding-left:20px" >' + value + '</span></div>';
}
```

and this style also

```
.googletooltip{
    color:#fff;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: #3882C4;
    background: #000;
    padding:2px 15px 2px 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Thank a lot

Comment: Can you show the codes that you are using for the chart as well as the tooltip properties above?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a top property and a position property for the .googletooltip class. If not, try using the margin property if the other properties are not working. Work around these three properties and see if you will be able to move tooltip up. Let me know if it still isn't working.

```
.googletooltip{
 color:#fff;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 2px;
 border-color: #3882C4;
 background: #000;
 padding:2px 15px 2px 15px;
 font-weight: bold;
 }
```

Comment: I also think I may modify the style of the tooltip. But i have no experience in html, css, so, can you suggest me what style elements (and value) shoule be added here ?

Comment: Try adding a top or position property inside your .googletooltip class. If these two properties doesn't have any effect on the position of the tooltip, use the margin property instead. All of these properties should be inside your .googletooltip class.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you calling createToolTip function? Is it called while generating data `chartData.addRows(data);`?

Ref: check how createCustomHTMLContent function is used @ https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_tooltip_content#custom_html_content

Comment: I have created the custom tooltip using html content and it work. But my question is how to move the tooltip to the top of the chart. I am not good in html, css, so I dont know how to do it.

Comment: In that case you will need to use position / top / margin properties as suggested by 宿命的な孤独. Refer http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp for understanding how it works.